# How to delete just a field in all documents if it exists

Tags: mongodb, optimization, database, nosql

I mistakenly applied an update query over all documents in the wrong MongoDB collection. Now I want to get rid of every `city.postcode` field with the value `W1` in the collection `person`.

Any hint?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

It should be something similar to this query, but it's not working:

```
db.person.update({$unset:{cast:1}}, false, true)
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample document schema?

Comment: See ["multi"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) in `.update()`, along with [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) Existing does not matter.

Comment: See ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). ie.  `db.comedy.update({},{ "$unset": { "city.postcode": "" } },{ "multi": true })`. And also read the documentation as [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) takes a "query" and an "update" statement. And going by your last question `W1` is not something `city.postcode` is "within".

Comment: @chridam sorry I think it's not neccessary

Comment: This is the solution db.example.update({},{$unset: {words:1}},false,true)

Comment: @stackpepe When you found the answer yourself, you can answer your own question. Answering your own questions is encouraged on stackexchange.